# How can I declare an array of unknown elements where the first one must be a string?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that accepts an array of arrays. The inner array can have any number of elements of any type, but the first one must be a string.

The following is a valid input array:

```
[
    ['2022-03-04T00:00:00Z', 64, 10],
    ['2022-03-05T00:00:00Z', 61, 12],
    ['2022-03-06T00:00:00Z', 66, 14],
]
```

But the following is not a valid input:

```
[
    [0, '2022-03-04T00:00:00Z', 64, 10],
    [1, '2022-03-05T00:00:00Z', 61, 12],
    [2, '2022-03-06T00:00:00Z', 66, 14],
]
```

I tried the following:

```
function formatDateLabels( array: [[string, ...any[]]] ){
    ...
}
```

but the compiler complains:

```
Argument of type '[[string, number, number], [string, number, number], [string, number, number]]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[[string, ...any[]]]'.
  Source has 3 element(s) but target allows only 1.(2345)
```

How can I declare the types correctly?

Comment: `[first: string, ...rest: any[]]`? See https://tsplay.dev/weXxaW. But the problem with `[[string, ...any[]]]` isn't in the type of each tuple, it's that you only allow a single one of them - `[string, ...any[]][]` would be fine.

Comment: This is very obvious from the compiler's "complaint", which I've added to your question - please include a [mre] when asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example's `[[string, ...any[]]]` parameter type is expecting a tuple that contains a single nested tuple with the first value being a string and allowing any other entry types after it.

This type should be changed to `[string, ...any[]][]` which expects an array of tuples that accept the first value as a string and any entry types after it.

```
function formatDateLabels(array: [string, ...any[]][]){
    // code
}

formatDateLabels([
    ['2022-03-04T00:00:00Z', 64, 10],
    ['2022-03-05T00:00:00Z', 61, 12],
    ['2022-03-06T00:00:00Z', 66, 14],
]);
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOAnAtgQygEWwUwBlMAjfAGwGcAKTVVTATwC5EBtSqVGMAcwBpEAOhGYwjNgF1JUgJQBvALAAoRGsQB6DYghwAJvhUBfFSpQZseKEVIUabFevYByAEwAGV64C07gMy+ACwAKu7uzGER7gBazoIAbIGCAIzukvyO6mxunj7+vgCsoeGRYbEJySmu6Zlq2R5evgHu8cVRUeWI8fEpgTXKkrIA3EA).

Comment: I see in the playground it works. But why does my code show the following error: "A rest element type must be an array type"?

Comment: Oh, that is because you are using TypeScript 4.0+. A new rule was introduced in that version for all 'rest' parameters (the ... syntax) to have a type that is an array. So ```[string, ...any][]``` should be changed to ```[string, ...any[]][]```. The behaviour is exactly the same for both, but the newer TypeScript versions prefer it the latter option. I will update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could create your own interface of specific types for the inner array.

The values for the above could be for example a string and then another array of type any, so that you can hold an infinite amount of items.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html